# For loops in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have been researching after finding a rule in tslint "prefer-for-of" and it appears that most people are of the opinion that a standard for loop should not be used within typescript, but I cannot find any reasoning as to why this is. I understand that there are for(...of...) and for(...in...) loops that can be used, but it seems that the standard for loop could  still be useful in certain situations. Can anyone explain the reasoning? Is this just for readability purposes, or are there any performance impacts that make the new styles better?

________________EDIT______________

I did a little more research and decided to see what the difference is within the rendered JavaScript, which I found a little helpful. While the standard for loop and for(...in...) both return the same values, they are of different types and the for(...of...) returns the actual values within the array. So, now I see the difference in the three different approaches, but I don't see if there is anything more than readability to make the decision on which to use, meaning I don't know if the for(...of...) is any more performant than the standard for loop in cases where the index isn't needed, or if it is just a little easier to read.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20x%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B'1'%2C%20'2'%2C%20'3'%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FLists%20the%20index%20values%0D%0Afor%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20x.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a.push(i)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a.push(typeof%20(i))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(a)%3B%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2FLists%20the%20index%20values%20the%20same%20as%20the%20for%20loop%0D%0Afor%20(let%20i%20in%20x)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a.push(i)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a.push(typeof%20(i))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aalert(a)%3B%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2FGoes%20through%20the%20actual%20values%20of%20the%20array%0D%0Afor%20(let%20i%20of%20x)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a.push(i)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a.push(typeof%20(i))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aalert(a)%3B)

Comment: See rationale: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/prefer-for-of/ -- standard for loops are still useful when you actually need the index though or are looping over a subset of the items.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887490/should-we-use-foreach-or-better-the-native-for-of-loop-in-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `for … of` to iterate through arrays because it has become the general way to proceed. The main thing is that JavaScript has evolved. Now, the general thing that can be iterated is an **Iterator**.

With an iterator, it is not possible to directly access to a data from its index. But we can still use a `for … of` loop.

An example:

```
const colors = new Map([
  [1, "red"], 
  [2, "green"], 
  [3, "blue"]
]);

for (colorName of colors.values())
  console.log(colorName)
```

The result will be:

```
red
green
blue
```

Here `colors.values()` [returns an iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), not an array. It wouldn't be possible to access its content using an index.

Some documentation: [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Regarding the performance, I suggest [this benchmark](https://jsperf.com/for-of-vs-for-loop/17). The traditional `for` loop is slightly better than `for … of`.